# Religious Institution Survey Information

Tags: data-request, geospatial, religion

I am after some data to assist in analysing religious bodies to detailed things like: -

- the frequency of attendance
- Giving/tithe
- demographic breakdown
- location data of the particular church/mosque/temple/etc.
- size of the members and adherents
- etc ...

But these data I am interested in finding out not on a national level, but on an individual church/mosque/temple basis. Some trending data would be great too.

I can find some data around these for USA institutions, but for the UK/Australia/Canada/NZL and other countries would be great too!

Comment: I'm guessing by U.S. data you mean the 2010 Religion Census, but ICYMI: http://www.rcms2010.org/

Comment: Yes this looks excellent!

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to spatial data you can give the Openstreemap a shot. You can get individual country data from [geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de/). I validated for New Zealand and from the Australia and Oceania area. From there you download the "New Zealand shapefile and open the shapefile called "gis.osm_pofw_free_1.shp" this will get you all different churches/temples.

Looking for the other data I can only speak from my experience in Germany but you wont get those details like attendance for single churches because of data protection issues. I found a  simple statistic for Germany through:

- [Catholics (german)](http://www.dbk.de/zahlen-fakten/kirchliche-statistik/) and low spatial resolution
- [Evangelic](http://www.ekd.de/english/4329-facts_and_figures_2016.html)