# How can I get all churches in the USA

Tags: usa

I'm looking to get info on all churches across the US. Specifically, I'd love to get:

1. Their address
2. Denomination
3. Active/Not
4. Contact Info (website, email, phone)

and any other info I can get.

Comment: Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10840/religious-institution-survey-information

Comment: By "church", do you mean Christian churches only (some people distinguish other houses of worship as mosques, synagogues, etc)? If so, there might be an organization that attempts to maintain a complete list.

Comment: Yes @BarryCarter, I meant Christian churches only. Do you perchance know of any such organization?

Comment: thank you for the rising of this thread and offering ideas .BTW - isnt it possible to go and use  overpass-turbo.eu - for a search?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [Open StreetMap data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) with Nominatom for your base file.

This should get you #1 and you can get #2 just by text mining their titles.

For #3 I believe the closest you'll get is just to use the most recent available data.

For #4 I think you'd need to do original data scraping from the Internet - at least to get their websites (I'm not sure on this one, actually).

Comment: just to expand a bit, you can get a list of all "places of worship" by downloading bulk osm files from geofabrik.de and then using use `osmfilter` or `osmosis` to select only certain tags, for example: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity=place_of_worship . More details --> https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511

Comment: hello Hack-R and philshem thank you for the rising of this thread and offering ideas .BTW - isnt it possible to go and use  overpass-turbo.eu - for a search?